# Creating passbook passes in iOS app

Tags: ios, passbook

Is it possible to create pkpass in app? I have watched a few wwdc and searched online. It say it require signing and it can't be created in app. Is it correct? If not, is there a way to create **in app**?

Comment: it is possible to do it, you should config in the https://developer.apple.com/ to enable pass

Comment: I have checked through online and github. Could you give me documentation?

Comment: We need to create pass identifier in dev portal so that it can be used to sign in server.

Comment: Thanks. but those are not for creating passes in iOS app.

Comment: the tutorial doc: https://www.raywenderlich.com/20734/beginning-passbook-part-1, I found some useful docs, but it is chinese, so I will not put them out.

Comment: passbook in iOS progress to wallet, so , I think you should study wallet, and the useful information is more:https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/technologies/wallet/   I tested the  raywenderlich.com/20734/beginning-passbook-part-1, find there is something already outtime, which is adapt to iOS 6

Comment: I have read that tutorial and passes are created outside app. (please let me know if i am wrong)

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is yes, but you probably don't want to. I don't see what would stop you creating and signing a PKPass file in ObjectiveC or Swift.

The reason you wouldn't want to do this is security. When a pass is created, it's manifest is signed with a private key. This ensures that you can trust the vendor and it also provides legal safeguards. If you put were to create the private key into the pass it could be extracted and use to create similar Passes or even replace your own passes.